# Swift - Facebook Graph API: How to convert date as String to hour:min:sec

Tags: swift, facebook, date, facebook-graph-api, utc

I get from Facebook-Graph-API, a date like "2019-05-06T08:39:43+0000" as String.

In swift, how to convert this date to, for example if i live in France (+2), "10:39:43" as String too ?

Comment: I'm pretty new in Stack Overflow, so i don't know why i get -2 for my question. Sorry if it's stupid and simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the time zone to +2 hours

```
let str =  "2019-05-06T08:39:43+0000"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 7200)

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str) {
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
  let strPlus2hours = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  print(strPlus2hours)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as i said above, i want a date like this "10:39:43", only hour:min:sec. So i modify your dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" to "HH:mm:ss" but it doesn't work, why ?